# Define global dataweave function in mule 3

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-esb, mulesoft

I am defining the global function for payload but in the dataweave 1.0 I am not able to do the task.
I have to define a separate global dataweave file where I have to add the conditions for payload like if gender== "male" then title= "mr."
How can I perform the task. I have added my input and expected payload.

input payload:

```
{
    "persons": [
        {
            "name": "Devendra",
            "gender": "male",
            "age": 25
        },
        {
            "name": "aman",
            "gender": "male",
            "age": 16
        }
    ]
}
```

expected payload:

```
{
    "persons": [
        {
            "title": "MR.",
            "name": "Devendra",
            "gender": "male",
            "age": 25,
            "adult": true
        },
        {
            "title": "MS.",
            "name": "Seema",
            "gender": "female",
            "age": 16,
            "adult": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dataweave 1 you can define a global library by creating a dwl file in src/main/resources like so:

src/main/resources/dw/myFunctions.dwl:

```
%dw 1.0
%function titleForGender(gender)("mr" when gender=="male" otherwise "whoKnows?")
---
{
"titleForGender": titleForGender
}
```

This script creates a global function and then exposes it in the body so its available to the other script.

Then in your main dw transformation something like this:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json

%var sampleData={persons:[{name:"Devendra", gender:"male",age:25}, {name:"aman", gender:"male",age:16}]}
%var lib = readUrl("classpath://dw/myfunctions.dwl")
 ---
persons: sampleData.persons map {
    "person": $ ++ {title: lib.titleForGender($.gender)}
}
```

It uses `readUrl` to read in the function from the global file as var `lib` and then uses it when mapping the person data, passing in the `gender` to the function and getting the title returned from the function.

This outputs:

```
{
  "persons": [
    {
      "person": {
        "name": "Devendra",
        "gender": "male",
        "age": 25,
        "title": "mr"
      }
    },
    {
      "person": {
        "name": "aman",
        "gender": "male",
        "age": 16,
        "title": "mr"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: what is the syntex to define multiple if else condition here- %function titleForGender(gender)("mr" when gender=="male" otherwise "whoKnows?")

Comment: Nest them: x when a==1 otherwise(y when a==2 otherwise( z)) and so on